# How Display Posts on category

Tags: php, posts, css, html

I had a problem, I converted an html template to wordpress, now I want a section Category Enable to display content using categories Does anyone know the solution and code?
iam use a code and not work for category :

```
 <?php
            $a = array(
                'posts_per_page'   =>200,
                'offset'           => 0,
                'cat'               => '',
                'category_name'    => '',
                'orderby'          => 'post_date',
                'order'            => 'DESC',
                'include'          => '',
                'exclude'          => '',
                'meta_key'         => '',
                'meta_value'       => '',
                'post_type'        => 'mahsulat',
                'post_mime_type'   => '',
                'post_parent'      => '',
                'post_status'      => 'publish',
                'suppress_filters' => true );

            $the_query=new WP_Query($a);
            while($the_query->have_posts())
            {
                $the_query->the_post();

            ?>
```

thank

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png). If you want to show an archive of your posts you create a template called `archive-mahsulat.php` where `mahsulat` is your post type. Then you can add a normal [WordPress Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) to the file so it can output posts of that type.

If you're looking to create a category page for your post type you first need to [register a taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/). Then you can create a archive page called `taxonomy-{$taxonomy}.php` where `{$taxonomy}` would be replaced with your specific taxonomy slug.

You don't need to create a custom secondary query for these things, if the PHP template pages exist and are named properly then WordPress will connect the dots and query the data for you.